# How to catch error in addToTag() [grails]

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have 2 domains .. master and details.

```
Master{
 String masterName; 
 static hasMany=[details:Detail]
}

Detail
{
  String detailName ; 
  static belongsTo =[master:Master];
}
```

I have form that handle the save

```
def save = {
 .....
 def master = new Master(params);
 params.detailsName.eachWithIndex(dtName, index ->
   def detail = new Detail();
   detail.detailName = dtName; 
   ....
   master.addToDetails(detail);
 }
  .....
 master.save(flush:true);
}
```

when I called master.save(), if there are errors in detail, the master still saving the data. I want to know how to cancel master if there are errors in details and i would like to know how to track the errors in details ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transaction is what you need.  You could perform the save in a service.  In services with transaction=true, all methods are wrapped in transactions and there will be an automated rollback if any exception is thrown:

```
class MasterService {

    boolean transactional = true

    def save(...) { }
}
```

Or you could use the [withTransaction](http://grails.org/doc/1.1.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html) closure in your controller to wrap your code in a transaction if you don't want to create a service.

Comment: i did using transaction, but i have no idea how to know that there is error/detail is not valid to be inserted (may be the name is blank or date is null etc).

as far as i know, when detail was not valid, the header still inserted and it caused detail couldn't be saved. 

once you addTo*() it will attach the object without raising any errors. but when you save() the detail wont saved if there are errors and i cannot get the error message.

Comment: You can check detail.validate() and if false you can check the errors using detail.errors.each { log.debug it }.